# How to set the “ —key-type” parameter and “--index” parameter of v1/chain/get_table_rows function?

Tags: multi-index

how to set as the --key-type and --index parameters when i use the http api "v1/chain/get_table_rows" as cleos commend "cleos get table eosio eosio namebids --key-type i64 --index 2".

the "--key-type" and "--index" is disable in "v1/chain/get_table_rows" ,what should i do?

links:
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/4053
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i have solved this question.

I execute the command ”*./cleos -u "http://dev.cryptolions.io:38888" get table xun xun cates --key-type i64 --index 2*“

then i get the socket data packets use wireshark.

i found this :

[image]

**cleos comment： --key-type   --index**

**rpc comment:   key_type         index_position**

Comment: A tip, use cleos --print-request to get the request detailes